# Parsing a url through bash

Tags: php, bash, curl, sed, wget

SO I'm working on a bash script I'm calling plugins.sh for a minecraft network we're getting ready to release. This plugin is supposed to detect if a plugin is current installed on a selected server. If its not, download the plugin, check to make sure it downloaded correctly. If it was there to begin with, remove it and download it again to update it. Unfortunantly, not every bukkit plugin I want to download has a build server I can download off of. CoreProtect is a perfect example of this, as its also got a version number tacked on the end of it.

If you look that this page here: http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/coreprotect/files/

those are all of the links to all of the files currently uploaded by the CoreProtect author. What I need to figure out how to do is to somehow get the first url in that file. Download the url, then scrape it for a .jar link, then download it. I'd rather keep this all inside of my script in one place. So I'd rather keep it within the constraints of wget, curl, bash and sed; things like that. I can give you guys the code I'm currently working on here in the form of a paste bin, as its a little long.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "shutting down $1 to backup safely"
service mc$1 stop
echo "Backing up $1's plugin files to the backup directory"
SIZE=`du -sk /home/$1/plugins/ | cut -f 1`
tar cf -  -C / home/$1/plugins/ | pv -p -s ${SIZE}k | \
     bzip2 -c > /home/backup/$1plugins$(date +%d%B%Y_%H:%M).tar.bz2
echo "backup complete, beginning plugin update progress"

if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/Essentials.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Essentials/dist/Essentials.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/Essentials.jar" ] && echo "Essentials has been installed" || echo "Essentials did not install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/Essentials.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Essentials/dist/Essentials.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/Essentials.jar" ] && echo "Essentials has been updated" || echo "Essentials did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsAntiBuild/dist/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsAntiBuild has been installed" || echo "EssentialsAntiBuild did not install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsAntiBuild/dist/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsAntiBuild.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsAntiBuild has been updated" || echo "EssentialsAntiBuild did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsChat.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsChat/dist/EssentialsChat.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsChat.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsChat has been installed" || echo "EssentialsChat did not install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsChat.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsChat/dist/EssentialsChat.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsChat.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsChat has been updated" || echo "EssentialsChat did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsProtect.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsProtect/dist/EssentialsProtect.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsProtect.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsProtect has been Installed" || echo "EssentialsProtect did not Install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsProtect.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsProtect/dist/EssentialsProtect.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsProtect.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsProtect has been updated" || echo "EssentialsProtect did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsSpawn.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsSpawn/dist/EssentialsSpawn.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsSpawn.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsSpawn has been Installed" || echo "EssentialsSpawn did not Install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/EssentialsSpawn.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.cookieslap.net/build/job/Essentials/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/EssentialsSpawn/dist/EssentialsSpawn.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/EssentialsSpawn.jar" ] && echo "EssentialsSpawn has been updated" || echo "EssentialsSpawn did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/NoCheatPlus.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://ci.md-5.net/job/NoCheatPlus/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/NoCheatPlus.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/NoCheatPlus.jar" ] && echo "NoCheatPlus has been Installed" || echo "NoCheatPlus did not Install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/NoCheatPlus.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://ci.md-5.net/job/NoCheatPlus/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/NoCheatPlus.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/NoCheatPlus.jar" ] && echo "NoCheatPlus has been updated" || echo "NoCheatPlus did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/PermissionsEx.jar ]
    then
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.bukkit.org/media/files/742/103/PermissionsEx.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/PermissionsEx.jar" ] && echo "PermissionsEx has been installed" || echo "PermissionsEx did not install correctly"
    else
        rm /home/$1/plugins/PermissionsEx.jar
        cd /home/$1/plugins/
        wget --quiet http://dev.bukkit.org/media/files/742/103/PermissionsEx.jar
        [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/PermissionsEx.jar" ] && echo "PermissionsEx has been updated" || echo "PermissionsEx did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.jar ]
    then
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".zip" http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful/?branch=master
            mv /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful/download/worldedit*.zip /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.zip
            unzip -q -o "WorldEdit*.zip"
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.zip
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.jar" ] && echo "WorldEdit has been installed" || echo "WorldEdit did not install correctly"
    else
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.jar
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".zip" http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful/?branch=master
            mv /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit/last-successful/download/worldedit*.zip /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.zip
            unzip -q -o "WorldEdit*.zip"
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.zip
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/WorldEdit.jar" ] && echo "WorldEdit has been updated" || echo "WorldEdit did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.jar ]
    then
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".zip" http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldguard/last-successful/?branch=master
            mv /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org/job/worldguard/last-successful/download/worldguard*.zip /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.zip
            unzip -q -o "WorldGuard*.zip"
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.zip
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.jar" ] && echo "WorldGuard has been installed" || echo "WorldGuard did not install correctly"
    else
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.jar
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".zip" http://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldguard/last-successful/?branch=master
            mv /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org/job/worldguard/last-successful/download/worldguard*.zip /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.zip
            unzip -q -o "WorldGuard*.zip"
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/builds.enginehub.org
            rm /home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.zip
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/WorldGuard.jar" ] && echo "WorldGuard has been updated" || echo "WorldGuard did not update correctly"
fi
if [ ! -f /home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar ]
    then
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet http://24.22.114.23/job/Vault/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/*zip*/target.zip
            unzip -q -o target.zip
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault-*-javadoc.jar
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault-*-sources.jar
            mv /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault*.jar /home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target.zip
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/target
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar" ] && echo "Vault has been installed" || echo "Vault did not install correctly"
    else
            rm /home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar
            cd /home/$1/plugins/
            wget --quiet http://24.22.114.23/job/Vault/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/*zip*/target.zip
            unzip -q -o target.zip
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault-*-javadoc.jar
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault-*-sources.jar
            mv /home/$1/plugins/target/Vault*.jar /home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar
            rm /home/$1/plugins/target.zip
            rm -rf /home/$1/plugins/target
            [ -f "/home/$1/plugins/Vault.jar" ] && echo "Vault has been updated" || echo "Vault did not update correctly"
fi



echo "Finished updating and or installing plugins, fixing permissions"
chown -R $1:$1 /home/$1/*
echo "Permissions fixed"
service mc$1 start
echo "Done"
```

If there is anyone that can help me in writing a bit of code here to figure out how to at least grab the first link in that table and download the page associated to the link. It would be greatly appreciated.

edit

I've made a little bit of progress on this. I was able to adapt something that I found on another stackoverflow thread.

```
site=http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/coreprotect/files/
curl -s $site | sed -rn 's/.[^0-9]*([0-9]+)(-core-protect-v)[^0-9]*([0-9.]+).*/\1\2/p'
```

this will print everything out, and I think I can echo this into a document and then use sed to pull out the first line and add in the rest of the url.. well at least I think its a start. Wonder if anyone else has a more elegant solution to this.

that and my regex is not working correctly and only pulling out the first 3/4 of the coreprotect part. Its not displaying the version numbers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be great to include the **relevant bits of your code** in your question and **explain** where exactly you're stuck. That way, you'd get more accurate answers. Personally, I feel this question is currently a bit broad/vague.

Comment: The pastebin link at the bottom of the question is the link to the code in question. But I don't have a problem specifically with the code itself, I need help in adding to it. Since its something I don't know how to do yet.

Comment: Just updated my post with some more current information

Comment: Alas, tl;dr. If you can refine your question so that you provide an example of the bit you're having trouble with, we can provide programming advice.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you asked:

```
site='http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/coreprotect/files/'
pluginurl=$(curl -s $site | sed -n -e '/CoreProtect v/{s/.*href="\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/;p;q}')

fullurl="http://dev.bukkit.org/$pluginurl"
jarurl=$(curl -s $fullurl | sed -n -e '/\.jar/{s/.*href="\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/;p;q}')

echo "$jarurl"
```

The first `sed` matches alla the lines containing "CoreProtect v" and extracts the content of the `href` attribute. Note that when the line is matched `sed` executes three commands:

- `s/.*href="\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/` replaces everything in the line except the `href` content;
- `p` prints the resulting value (that is only the `href` content);
- `q` exits immediately after the first match, so you get only the first URL in the page. If you want more lines you have to remove this command.

At this point you have the URL except for the domain part that we are going to add in the `fullurl` variable.

The next `sed` operates on the content of `fullurl` and is similar to the preceding one because it matches the lines with `.jar` in them and executes three commands:

- `s/.*href="\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/` replaces everything in the line with the content of the `href` attribute;
- `p` prints;
- `q` exits after the first match.